# Have the ServiceStack v3 libraries been removed from Nuget?

Tags: nuget, servicestack, servicestack-bsd

Does anyone know how I can get the V3 version of `ServiceStack.Client` off Nuget? This wiki page appears to suggest that they should be there: https://github.com/ServiceStackV3/ServiceStackV3

I need to create a new project to interact with a legacy v3 ServiceStack implementation. I can't upgrade the existing API, but the `JsonServiceClient` in the new v4 is not compatible. I've imported the contracts DLL from our legacy API, which is causing the incompatibility issue.

The exact error is:

> Error 105 The type 'ServiceStack.ServiceHost.IReturn' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'ServiceStack.Interfaces, Version=3.9.48.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.   D:\Projects\Adactus.Pulse\Main\Solutions\Integration\Mulesoft\SupplierIntegration\ScmtProcessor\InitialInstructionProcessor.cs  231 17  ScmtProcessor

Have they been moved by chance to a different nuget package name (i.e. the BSD version)? Or do I need to manually start copying DLL references around?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No they haven't been moved, you can see all the NuGet package versions listed on NuGet:

- https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack/
- https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Common/

You'll need to download the exact v3.9.48 packages you need, which the v3 page you linked to shows an example of:

https://github.com/ServiceStackV3/ServiceStackV3

Comment: Ah, I was looking at ServiceStack.Client forgetting that the old client is in ServiceStack.Common. Thanks as ever for your support @mythz